# Sending all webpage requests from uiwebview through a proxy server

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, proxy, http-headers, httpresponse

I have an app and a server that I am working with. The server acts as a proxy server. In my app, I have a uiwebview which sends a request to the proxy server. The proxy server then generates a response for the uiwebview, sending back the requested page, but the problem is that the uiwebview does not load any of the the resource urls in the page such as style sheets, images etc. through the proxy server.

My question is, is there a way to send a response from the proxy server back to the uiwebview, telling the uiwebview to load all the resources through the proxy server, or is there a way to change all resource url requests made by a uiwebview to point to the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read up about NSURLProtocol and see if that will meet your requirements to change the url requests to the proxy.